# Sorry, your bank wasn't able to verify your VISA **** at this time. Please choose another way to pay

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal

For  integrate paypal express checkout,i have created accounts in  paypal and other 2 accounts in sandbox for testing.After entered into sandbox paypal account ,there is button 'continue'and when i click on that button .it show error like

Sorry, your bank wasn't able to verify your VISA x-8285 at this time. Please choose another way to pay.
can you please give a solution for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is not PayPal tech support.